# How can I disable Alt menu launching?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Using Ubuntu 18. In several applications, Ubuntu appears to be intercepting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to engage the application's Menu. This interferes with my programming workflow in, say, Spyder. How to disable this behavior? I've google searched without success.

I have attempted the following fixes without success:

1. Disabling all <kbd>Alt</kbd> commands in Settings -> Keyboard
2. Using gnome tweak tool, set "Alt/Win key behavior" to "disabled"

Comment: It is doubtful you are running Ubuntu 18. Is it 18.04 or 18.10?

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases that use *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18), and *yy.mm* format (eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop).  The *yy* or *year* only releases are *snap* only, so GNOME runs inside a snap and settings are more limited & slightly different as programs work confined ... you should be precise as to which system you're meaning; a Ubuntu *snap* only release such as Ubuntu Core 18, or a standard desktop/server release such as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop/Server - they do differ.